# Mongodb update object in multi nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update an object that is inside a multi nested array in Mongodb. I know that I cannot use the positional $ operator for multi nested arrays. So I'm trying to use arrayFilters instead.

Here is my query structure:

```
var objTest = {
    name: 'blah',
    color: 'blablah'
}

SomeModel.updateOne(
    {
        an_id: anId,
        "an_array.another_array.and_another_array.some_id": id,
    },
    {
        $set: {
            "an_array.$[element].another_array.$[another_element].and_another_array": objTest,
        },
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [
            { "element.name": 'test' },
            { "another_element.id": 'test2' },
        ],
    }
)
.then((result) => {
    console.log("result ", result);
    resolve(result);
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log("err is ", err);
    reject(err);
});
```

So as per the example, I'm trying to update the object that matches `some_id` in the `and_another_array` array. When I try this, I'm receiving the error `The top-level field name must be an alphanumeric string beginning with a lowercase letter, found 'another_element'`

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out what the issue was. For some reason, mongodb didn't like the in another_element. renaming it to anotherelement worked.